# String Formatting with Decimal Number Python

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, decimal, string-formatting, floating-accuracy

I am working on building a report. One figure on the report needs to be expressed in millions. I wrote some basic formatters to handle various types of formatting that need to be consistent throughout the report. To do this, I use lambda functions and string formatting. The two functions are below. One is to round, the other to format.

```
formatter_round = lambda x: 0 if (x is None or x is bool) else round(x/1000000,1)

formatter_dollar = lambda x: '${:,.1}'.format(0) if (x is None or x == 0) else ('${:,.1}'.format(x) if x >= 0 else '$({:,.1})'.format(abs(x)))
```

Now comes the problem. See my example below.

I am dealing with two numbers, `a = 350000` and `b = 850000`.

For `a` everything works as I'd expect. The float isn't necessarily correct when rounded ( not "what I'd expect", but understandable behavior), but the decimal is correct.

```
a = 350000

formatter_dollar(formatter_round(a))
Out[89]: '$0.3'

a = Decimal(a)

formatter_dollar(formatter_round(a))
Out[91]: '$0.4'
```

When I run the same example with `b`, however, this breaks down.

```
b = 850000

formatter_dollar(formatter_round(b))
Out[93]: '$0.8'

b = Decimal(b)

formatter_dollar(formatter_round(b))
Out[95]: '$0.8'
```

My question is, how can I properly round and display numbers?

I thought my issue was floating point numbers, and `a` seemed to confirm that. Then when I ran the same with `b`, I realized that isn't the case.

Comment: You say that the example with `b` "breaks down". What do you mean by that? The values I see are the ones I'd expect to see. What values were you expecting, and why?

Comment: And are you aware that Python's default rounding mode is [round-ties-to-even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)?

Comment: I mean that it doesn't round the way I'd expect. Thank you for the link pertaining to round-ties-to-even, that's very helpful. I was actually looking for more info on the default rounding behavior. Now that I know the proper name, I am looking to do "round half up" rounding. Is it possible to change the round type in python?

Comment: Not for floats, but the rounding mode is configurable for the `Decimal` type; the documentation has details of how to do this.